# How do you add uneditable text in an iOS app

Tags: ios, uikit

I now a label can create static text, but I have a few paragraphs that are neatly formatted that need to go to my app. How can I do this without using a label?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a label?

Comment: Label is the perfect option for the scenario you've described, so without an explanation of why a label does not work for you, I must downvote and close vote as unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `UITextView` and set the `editable` property to `NO`